# web Crawling and Extracting data using scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am new to python as well as scrapy.
I am trying to crawl a seed url https://www.health.com/patients/status/.This seed url contains many urls. But I want to fetch only urls that contain Faci/Details/#somenumber from the seed url  .The url will be like below:

```
https://www.health.com/patients/status/ ->https://www.health.com/Faci/Details/2                                                                                                        
                                   -> https://www.health.com/Faci/Details/3
                                   -> https://www.health.com/Faci/Details/4



https://www.health.com/Faci/Details/2 -> https://www.health.com/provi/details/64
                                 -> https://www.health.com/provi/details/65


https://www.health.com/Faci/Details/3 -> https://www.health.com/provi/details/70
                                 -> https://www.health.com/provi/details/71
```

Inside each https://www.health.com/Faci/Details/2  page there is   https://www.health.com/provi/details/64
https://www.health.com/provi/details/65 ... .Finally I want to fetch some datas from 
https://www.health.com/provi/details/#somenumber  url.How can I achieve the same?

As of now I have tried the below code from scrapy tutorial and able to crawl only url that contains https://www.health.com/Faci/Details/#somenumber .Its not going to https://www.health.com/provi/details/#somenumber .I tried to set depth limit in settings.py file.But it doesn't worked.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from news.items import NewsItem


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'provdetails.com'
allowed_domains = ['health.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.health.com/patients/status/']

rules = (

  Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/Faci/Details/\d+', )),  follow=True),

  Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/provi/details/\d+', )),callback='parse_item'),                  
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    self.logger.info('Hi, this is an item page! %s', response.url)
    item = NewsItem()
    item['id'] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
    item['name'] = response.xpath("//title/text()").extract()
    item['description'] = response.css('p.introduction::text').extract()
    filename='details.txt'
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(item)
    self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)
    return item
```

Please help me to proceed further?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the regex-based and mighty `Rule/LinkExtractor` gave me often a hard time. For simple project it is maybe an approach to extract all links on page and then look on the `href` attribute. If the href matches your needs, `yield` a new [`Response`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) object with it. For instance:

```
 from scrapy.http import Request
 from scrapy.selector import Selector
...
    # follow links
    for href in sel.xpath('//div[@class="contentLeft"]//div[@class="pageNavigation nobr"]//a').extract():
            linktext = Selector(text=href).xpath('//a/text()').extract_first()
            if linktext and linktext[0] == "Weiter":
                    link = Selector(text=href).xpath('//a/@href').extract()[0]
                    url = response.urljoin(link)
                    print url
                    yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Some remarks to your code:

```
    response.xpath(...).extract()
```

This will return a list, maybe you want to have a look on [`extract_first()`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) which provide the first item (or `None`).

```
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
```

This will overwrite the file several times. You will only gain the last item saved. Also you open the file in binary mode (`'b'`). From the filename I guess you want to read it as text? Use `'a'` to append? See [open() docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)
An alternative is to use the [`-o` flag](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) to use scrapys facilities to store the items to JSON or CSV.

```
    return item
```

It is a good style to `yield` items  instead of return them. At least if you need to create several items from one page you need to `yield` them.

Another good approach is: *Use one parse() function for one type/kind of page*.

For instance every page in `start_urls` fill end up in `parse()`. From that you extract could extract the links and `yield` `Request`s for each `/Faci/Details/N` page with a callback `parse_faci_details()`. In `parse_faci_details()` you extract again the links of interest, create `Request`s and pass them via `callback=` to e.g. `parse_provi_details()`.
In this function you create the items you need.